# How load multiple weight for some layers in keras?

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

I wanna Train network contain multiple (two and more) parallel CNN which common in last full connected layers, but i want use transfer learning method to train this networks separately at first and then merge them and fine tune my network.

How I Can Do It by `Keras`?

Comment: What have you tried yourself, what problems did you run into?

Comment: I use ```model.load_weights("model.h5",by_name=True)```, to solve my problem and check loaded weights by ```model.get_weight()```. so i think my problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what you need: [Transfering weights from one layer to another](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize#saving_loading_only_the_models_weights_values)